# How to store a future without boxing it

Tags: rust, traits, rust-futures

I want to do the following

```rust
struct Stored<F: Future<Output = ()>> {
    f: Option<F>,
}

impl<F: Future<Output = ()>> Stored<F> {
    fn store(&mut self, f: F) {
        let f = async {};
        self.f = Some(f);
    }
}
```

But it gives me the error:

```
expected type parameter `F`
      found opaque type `impl futures::Future<Output = ()>`
type parameters must be constrained to match other types
```

I could solve it boxing the future, but if the method `store` was the only place I stored this future, there would be no need to do that, because all the future blocks would be always the same type. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because `F` is a generic type provided from outside of the `Stored` type, but the actual type of the future is an unnamed type provided from within the `store` associated function (created by `async {}`). There is no possible way that `F` can be specified to be the correct type.

The way this is usually handled is to create a dedicated, nameable type implementing `Future`.  In this trivial case, that could be [`std::future::Ready<()>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/struct.Ready.html):

```
struct Stored {
    f: Option<std::future::Ready<()>>,
}

impl Stored {
    fn store(&mut self) {
        self.f = Some(std::future::ready(()));
    }
}
```

If the type of the future actually does come from outside of the type, then you just need to adjust your code to use `f` directly instead of discarding it and using `async {}`:

```
use std::future::Future;

struct Stored<F> {
    f: Option<F>,
}

impl<F: Future> Stored<F> {
    fn store(&mut self, f: F) {
        self.f = Some(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: On nightly, you can use `type_alias_impl_trait`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yep, I'm very much looking forward to using that when it's standardized. (Hopefully this decade.)

Comment: The lang team wants async fn in traits by the end of the year, but they may stabilize them without stabilizing `type_alias_impl_trait` :(